# Conditional Formatting using Multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I want to highlight cells based on a condition I have a table with sales people I want to Highlight the rows with a sales person selected via a Data validation cell (that I accomplished and now what I want to do is highlight the Max and Min values dependeing of the salesperson I selected in the drop down

Comment: Can you provide an example? In general, you can use sumproduct function for multiple conditions.

Comment: See [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Conditional%20Formatting%20using%20Multiple%20criteria.xlsb) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conditional formatting formula you can use in the example you provided:

=AND($A2=$O$2, OR(B2=MAX($B2:$J2), B2=MIN($B2:$J2)))

Apply the conditional formatting formula to cell range B2:J5 (the range of numbers, excluding the name of sales people)

Explanation:

- $A2=$O$2 - This part checks for the name of the sales person
- B2=MAX($B2:$J2) - This checks for the Max value in the row
- B2=MIN($B2:$J2) - This checks for the Min value in a row

If you wanted to have different colors for Min and Max values, you can create two separate conditional formatting rules that separate our Min / Max:

- =AND($A2=$O$2, B2=MAX($B2:$J2))
- =AND($A2=$O$2, B2=MIN($B2:$J2))

The way relative references are used here are key. I'd recommend looking up a tutorial online if you need an explantion on how they work. Here's a pretty good one: excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html

A good article with details on using array formulas (MIN/MAX) in conditional formatting: http://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/june-2016-excel-array-formulas-in-conditional-formatting/

[Here's a screenshot of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVyZI.png)